# Can I ground a detached garage to adjacent soil instead of connecting back to the panel?

Tags: wiring, grounding, 240v, old-house, retrofit

I have a 50s house that has some 10/3 without ground for 240v/30a running to the garage.

It's easier to run a ground wire to the outside of the garage and to the earth than it is back to the panel. Is that allowed?

Follow up, does the grounding wire have to be insulated if it is visible?

I want to do this right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the garage have a sub panel or does the wire just go to a receptacle/outlet?

Comment: The wire goes to a junction box. No sub panel.

Comment: The experts will weigh in but I think what @crip659 is getting at is that a safety ground ("Equipment Grounding Conductor" or EGC) path needs to eventually connect back to the main panel so any fault triggers a breaker there. Going into the dirt instead is unlikely to trigger a breaker reliably.  In recent years, Code has given great flexibility on how exactly the path gets to the panel.

Comment: I see. So the options are run it back to the panel or get a sub panel. Thank you both!

Comment: No, a sub panel won't correct your deficiency, which is the lack of a ground conductor in your #10 cable to the garage.  A sub panel has two separate grounding bus bars, one for the neutral, and one for ground (earth), and they need to be kept separate from one another in a sub panel.  The only place those two are connected together is in the main panel.

Comment: In the lucky case that your cable to the garage is in metal conduit, that metal conduit can likely serve as the "wiring" for the ground run back to the main panel.

Comment: Grounding wire can be bare, but depending on the maximum fault current expected it may need to be a certaiin minimum gauge, and based on its gauge it may need to be mechanically protected by e.g. running it in conduit.

Comment: A Junction box is only one part of the circuit.  What does the circuit do/where does it go in the garage?  It seems that to make it it safe, will probably need a sub panel(easy to install yourself) and ground wire back to the main panel.  I imagine that it does not power just something like a dryer.

Answer (score 4):

### Not safe... might be grandfathered.

NM type cable (Romex) isn't allowed outdoors, so if that's what it is, that's the end of the conversation.

An old ungrounded **subpanel feeder** is "grandfathered in the law" if it was installed properly using the code that applied at the time the permit was pulled (prior to 2008 presumably)... it just isn't very safe.

This sounds like it is a MWBC (shared neutral) **branch circuit**, and running that ungrounded was outlawed in 1966 (pre-moonshot) or earlier than that, as early as NEC 1955.  If it was built with the house, you'd need to look at Code that was in force when the permit was pulled to build the house.

### Why it's not safe

If you want a full debrief on HOW it isn't safe, well, the British actually know a lot about that because they are moving to that system (for some reason).  You can [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE) (and just imagine there's a second hot wire there; the British only have 1 hot wire, but all the other stuff applies).  And if you're EV charging, it gets really weird:[see this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZVx7GbAwlg).

Having a local ground rod doesn't help that much, as the second video discusses.  Dirt isn't a very good conductor, that's why we have copper mines instead of just wrapping dirt in insulation lol.

The ground rods are there to suppress lightning and ESD, and keep the dirt around the garage about the same voltage as the electrical ground.  However if an appliance has bolted fault hot to ground, it will try to pull the local dirt up to 120V, and the dirt doesn't conduct well enough to stop it.  That' why a ground WIRE is now code.

### What you can do

Now one thing we can do, that the British *can't*, is stick a GFCI breaker at the supply end (at the house).  That will eliminate the hazards at the risk of creating annoying trips when a ground fault does happen.  Doing so will require you to separate your neutral from ground at the subpanel.    This won't comply with Code but will render it effectively quite a lot safer.

Another option which is Code compliant, if you can live with 120V, you can permanently convert one hot wire to ground by destroying all wire insulation anywhere it is reachable. (i.e. don't open up the sheath, just remove it up to the sheath so it is an obvious bare wire).  Take special care to choose *the same* wire at both ends.

The gold-plated way to do this is make the former neutral ground and install a 7.5 kVA to 10 kVA transformer at the garage. (quality unit like Baldor or Square D, not some mail order junk). Then, you can send 240V-only to the transformer primary, and pull 120/240V off the transformer secondary.  That's the "I want decent level 2 EV charging" option.

Comment: OP says it is only a junction box, no panel.

Comment: @crip659 then it would need to be 1966 or even earlier to be grandfathered.